# File creation in vhdl

Tags: vhdl

Instead of just taking input from a file and writing output to a file, is there a way to dynamically  creating a file from the VHDL design??

I am trying to create multiple files depending on number of fpgas connected to the system ( which can be varying).

thanks in advance

Comment: Create files where? Connected to which system? You can create and write files during simulation on the simulating machine, but FPGA running your design can't create any files.

Comment: Some synthesis tools can also create and write files (e.g. Xilinx XST -  Vivado does not support this feature). Because the path for file_open is a string, you can assemble any valid filename and pass it to this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, but maybe you mean this:

```
process
    file outputf : text;
begin
    file_open(outputf, "path/to/file", WRITE_MODE); -- READ_MODE and APPEND_MODE as the other options
    -- Do your file operation as usual
    file_close(outputf);
end process;
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a file name based on the instance of some entity:
each file created has the postfix of 'DATA_NAME' (for example)
Is this what you mean?

```
entity ENTITY_NAME is
   generic (
      DATA_NAME            : Character                       := '1'
   );
port (
...
);

architecture rtl of ENTITY_NAME is

[signals]

file file_out : TEXT open write_mode is "data_out/ENTITY_NAME" & DATA_NAME & ".txt";

begin

Proc_Data_Output : process
    variable line_out   : LINE;
begin

    d_inout <= "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ"; 

    write      (line_out, string'("Data: "));
    hwrite     (line_out, d_inout);
    writeline  (file_out, line_out);
    
end process;

end rtl;
```